# Onedrive REST API Cannot upload file with 322 bytes lenght

Tags: onedrive

I came across weird problem when testing upload files via OneDrive API. 
Most of the files are upload without problems but with few I have problems.

The one thing they have in common is the length - 322 bytes. 
When I try to PUT file I receive below error:

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Does this happen consistently or is intermittent?

Comment: It happens consistently for this one file. After further tests it turns out it is not the problem of OneDrive API because I was able to upload file via FireFox HttpRequester. It must be the problem of .NET HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you're still having issues can you paste in the .NET code you're using (assuming you can get it down to a concise repro)? Maybe we'll spot something that will help you.